# Google Maps API InfoWindow Incorrect Height on iPhone/Android Browser

Tags: iphone, android, html, css, google-maps

I have a web page that uses Google Maps API v3 to display markers with infowindows where my company has locations.

Whenever I'm on an iPhone or Android phone and have the device turned in landscape mode, the infowindow height is too small to see the content and no scrollbars appear (included photo shows what I mean). When the device is in portrait mode, the infowindows display correctly.

I've tried setting the height and min-height CSS properties of the HTML that makes up the content of the infowindows, but that has not worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To change this, you need to detect orientation change and redraw your window, something like:

```
document.addEventListener("orientationChanged", updateOrientation, false);
function updateOrientation(e) {
// resize window here
    wrapperH = window.innerHeight;
    document.getElementById('map_container').style.height = wrapperH + 'px';
}
```

This should work for the resizing, and I can't remember the API redraw call, but there is one for changing size.  Hope this helps.